# Enable included annotation based on MyCustomAnnotation flag

Tags: spring-boot, annotations, swagger-2.0

Can an included Annotation being omitted base on the CustomAnnotation's flag. i.e.:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE })
@Documented
@ApiImplicitParams({ @ApiImplicitParam(name = "Authorization",
                                       value = "Authorization token",
                                       dataType = "string",
                                       paramType = "header")
                   })
public @interface OAuth {
    @AliasFor("enabled") boolean value() default true;

    @AliasFor("value") boolean enabled() default true;
}
```

when OAuth is enabled:

```
@OAuth(true)
public void requireAuthorizationInHeader() {}
```

the `ApiImplicitParams` will be included because OAuth is `true`

on the other hand,

```
@OAuth(false)
public void notRequireAuthorizationInHeader() {}
```

the `ApiImplicitParams` should **not** be in effect.

Comment: Can you just *not* put the annotation when you don't need a header?

Comment: yes.  I could have removed the annotation when not needed.  I wanted to see if the included annotation(ApiImplicitParams) could somehow be disable if @OAuth is there with enabled=false.